# how could I convert raw svg data into image with svg format or png

Tags: svg

I got a raw data like

I want to know how to get it into image

```
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
```

Comment: Turn it into a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: i tried but failed ~_~ is there any service or python tool can do that ? thanks

Comment: The raw data in your question is incomplete, it ends in the middle of the file.